# Rails and ajax : act_as_votable behavior

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have created a like button to like posts on my application, but I want that the like append without refresh the page to see de +1 on the count and the "hearth" button get fill or not. I tried the following code, but I have this error :

```
jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255 PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/12/like 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my _posts.html.erb file :

```
<div class="vote-rv">
          <% if current_user.liked? post %>
            <%= link_to "", dislike_post_path(post), class: "dislike fa fa-heart", method: :put, remote: true %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to "", like_post_path(post), class: "like fa fa-heart-o", method: :put, remote: true %>
          <% end %>
          <span class="badge" data-id="<%= post.id %>"><%= post.get_likes.size %></span>
          </div>
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
resources :travels, :shallow => true do
        # Posts
        resources :posts do
            member do
                put "like" => "posts#like"
                put "dislike" => "posts#dislike"
            end
        end
    end
```

Here is my posts_controller.rb (like and dislike method)

```
def like
        @post.like_from current_user
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :back }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            format.js { render :layout => false }
        end
    end

    def dislike
        @post.dislike_by current_user
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :back }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            format.js { render :layout => false }
        end
    end
```

Any idea of what is the problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: but where is your js.erb file (response to ajax request)? You should have the like.js.erb and dislike.js.erb files in your post views filder

Comment: @J.D. I was sure that something missing, but what I have to put in these files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include two `js.erb` files, one called `like.js.erb` and one called `dislike.js.erb`, these respond to both the like and dislike methods in your controller.

Here is an example of the `like.js.erb` ajax file. This goes under views/posts, in the same folder as your `_posts.html.erb` file:

```
$('.like').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $('<%= post.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript post.get_likes.size %>');
    $('#like_<%= post.id %>').removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
});
```

For the `dislike.js.erb` file, you need to do a similar thing but switch the class names around, and change the `post.get_likes.size` to `post.get_dislikes.size` and add that line in your views if you actually want to see the dislike count

You also need to add an ID to the like view so that the ajax change of heart works properly:

```
<%= link_to "", like_post_path(post), id: "like_<%= post.id %>", class: "like fa fa-heart-o", method: :put, remote: true %>
```

Change your like and dislike methods to:

```
@post.liked_by current_user
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
end

@post.disliked_by current_user
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
end
```

Comment: What if my _posts.html.erb is in the travel folder ? I put both js file in traval folder where the _post.html.erb file is or in post folder ?

Comment: Put the js files in the same folder as the `_posts.html.erb` yes

Comment: I try your precedent code, but I already have to refresh page to see transformations, and there is still this error : `UT http://localhost:3000/posts/14/dislike 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: And it seems that my js file are not displayed because I put a console log on the first line function, to display a string, and in my console, nothing appear

Comment: I try but i still have the same issue, and for the id in the link, are you sure that is `id: "#like_<%= post.id %>"` ? maybe : `id: "like_#{post.id}"` is better, no ?

Comment: Yep my bad, leave out the #

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129843/discussion-between-antonin-mrchd-and-luka).